# Miscellaneous quest text present even after quest completion

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I’ve completed the quest ‘Find the word of power at Archwind’ , but the text is still there in the miscellaneous. What to do?

Comment: What is the precise text you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arcwind_Point_(Skyrim)#Bugs) with the Arcwind Point word wall:

> If Arngeir gives Arcwind Point as the location of a Word of Power, finding the word wall and learning the word may not complete the "Find the Word of Power in Arcwind Point" miscellaneous quest objective. The quest marker will remain in front of the word wall. The word wall located at Northwind Summit completes this quest, but only if it has not been previously found
>
> The console command `SetStage FreeFormHighHrothgarA 20` can be used to complete the quest, however Arngeir may give the quest again. Setting Arcwind Point as cleared via `SetLocationCleared fd685 1` will prevent getting sent there again.
>
> Since finding the word wall at Northwind Summit is the only known way to resolve this bug, this can be avoided by discovering the Arcwind Point word wall before the Northwind Summit one. (in PC SSE 1.4.2.0.8 it greybeards might still give you this wall if you "fixed" this bug by getting Northwind Summit)